# How to change string application id in google App Console?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application id similar to `com.example.test`. Is it possible to change it in App Console?

Comment: No you cannot change the package name from console

Comment: can tech support help with this?

Comment: No. You can not. You can change it from application code only.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that from the console, you will need to do it from the app and release an update.

Comment: google spears if the package name in the code and in the app console do not match